# MPLAB X IDE 2.05 cannot write in Microchip dsPIC30F6014A

Tags: mplab, dspic

We are working with e-pucks real robots which posses a Microchip dsPIC30F6014A. We work in Windows 8.1 at 64 bits with MPLAB X IDE 2.05 and 3.55. Our robots got a problem with the PIN number so you told us that the solution was to buy a ICD programmer to re-flash the firmware in the e-puck and recover their PIN for the bluetooth connection.

We got the ICD 3, the cable to re-flash and start working in MPLAB X IDE 2.05.  But, initially we could not program the robot for a permission of memory which suggested the following image[image] with this configuration and we tried to program it again. We got stuck with this message:

---

```
   Target detected
   Target Device ID (0x0) does not match expected Device ID (0x2c30000).
   Invalid command response (sent 0x5f, received 0x3f)
   Failed to read device
   Unable to download program executive
   Failed to program device
   Failed to send bulk data
   Failed writing builk data (memory type 8, address 0
   Invalid command response (sent 0x60, received 0x3f)
```

---

We tried to erase the flash device as indicated in Section 5.5 from http://www.gctronic.com/doc/index.php/E-Puck and it brought us this message:

---

```
   Connecting to MPLAB ICD 3...
   Firmware Suite Version.....01.30.09
   Firmware type..............dsPIC30F

   Target detected
   Device ID Revision = 1041

   Erasing...
   Erase successful
```

---

Then, we tried again to program the robot and got the same message

---

```
   Target detected
   Target Device ID (0x0) does not match expected Device ID (0x2c30000)
   ...
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I forgot to answer this question, the problem was insufficient energy from my USB port, the solution was to use a two male-female wire to drain energy from 2 port

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with specific controller. But MPLAB usually throws this error if the pin connection are wrong or you may have missed clock or data lines. easiest way will be using IPE tool and trying the connection. If IPE connects try programming with .HEX file